# Can there be a live home-work session on programmers?

Tags: discussion

Why can't there be a live home-work session or a practical real-time application development session to give a feel to new-comers of what actually development is. This could also help in the imparting best industry practices at an early time

Answer (score 6):

This could be something to organise in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21).

On DIY we have a regular [Project Update Thursday](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/schedule/export/111/188) where people come along and talk about their latest DIY projects (or not).

If people think that this might work, then we'll need to come up with some guidelines on:

- how often the sessions were run
- how long the sessions would be
- what sort of topics to discuss

etc.